# .PSD to .PNG for the Web: .png image not visible? Smart Objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I got a huge .psd file from a designer. My goal is to save parts of it as transparent .png images and embed them into my web page.

The odd thing is that most people cannot see my PNGs. JPEGs are visible, but I need to keep the image background transparent so I'm not using jpegs.

Here's one example: Do you see one or two images?
http://3dp-site.alexbelinsky.com/img-test.html

Here's what I have in Photoshop:
[image]

Are vector objects messing up my pngs? I have tried all possible setting in Photoshop, including the legacy Save for the Web. 
The pngs are not showing up in my browser but I see them on my computer through Image Viewer(Windows).
Most people say they can't see my pngs either.

What is going on? 
My .psd file is huge. I have no idea what the designer used to create it (AI?).

Part of this file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JZdnWoJVu6PcKQJNefU9jCK7iA4ugjAn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When I try to view the png directly using the image URL, Firefox says: `The image "view-source:http://3dp-site.alexbelinsky.com/thermateur-mobile.png" cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.`, and the image also fails to load in Chrome. I can see the jpeg in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Billy Kerr, so you are having the same issue. I am assuming hat something happens when I save the image in PS but can't quite figure out what exactly.

Comment: Firefox says "contains errors". So, I suspect the file is corrupted. As to the reason, I doubt it's Photoshop.  Does the PNG open in a browser? Try dragging the PNG file from your computer into an open browser window.

Answer (score 1):

50MB is "huge"?? Times sure have changed.

There's *nothing* wrong with that file.

I was able to open it and subsequently both save a png using Save For Web...

[image]

and quick export as a png...

[image]

The raster-based quality of that layer is a bit questionable, but the layer exports fine. (Note that the image quality of the above images matches the original file, it didn't degrade upon export/save for web).

If people "can't see your png" you are going to need to ask them what that means.

For example at your link.... http://3dp-site.alexbelinsky.com/img-test.html the HTML loads fine and shows the image, but there's also a *broken* image which fails to appear --> http://3dp-site.alexbelinsky.com/thermateur-mobile.png *You* may be viewing a cached result or have permissions the rest of the world does not have. This could be a permissions issue with the server and the image file itself completely unrelated to Photoshop.

Comment: It's interesting that you managed to save the file successfully. I wonder why when I save it it turns out broken. Even on my local machine I can't see it in my browser. Must be my image saving settings then. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You might consider bad RAM or a failing HDD. If an image can't be saved correctly, that means there's something causing an issue with the "write" process.

Comment: Has something been changed on the sample site? I see two images and the failing one also shows up just fine for me—but that’s on mobile Safari, so perhaps this browser is just better at ignoring the errors in the file, whatever they are. (And as Scott says, 50 MB is very far from huge for a Photoshop file. I managed to grind my computer to a steady-but-slow pace by working on an 168 GB file a few weeks ago—that was what I’d call huge. Thankfully also very rare.)

Comment: I have not changed the sample page. Interesting that some people see the image while others do not.

Comment: I just took another look.. That image still doesn't show for me. --> http://3dp-site.alexbelinsky.com/thermateur-mobile.png <-- (Yes I cleared caches as well)